# Get Full HD UImage from UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera without capture button click

Tags: iphone, opencv, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, face-detection

On a constant frequency I want to retrieve UIImage for some functionality

```
if (!_updateTimer) {
    _updateTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.updateFrequency
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(updateLocations:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES] retain];
}
```

where `self.updateFrequency = 1 / 20.0;`

How can I retrieve image constantly every second without clicking capture button ?

Following code is no use of me as it will give image size of iphone 320*480

```
CGImageRef cgoriginal = UIGetScreenImage();
CGImageRef cgimg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgoriginal, rect);
```

I need complete image which all are coming infront of camera on every frequent interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `takePicture` method whenever u want to capture image. You will get the image in the delegate methods.

```
extern CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();

CGImageRef cgoriginal = UIGetScreenImage();
CGImageRef cgimg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgoriginal, rect);            
UIImage *viewImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];    
CGImageRelease(cgoriginal);                
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
```

Comment: i know takePicture method. But I cannot call takePicture every second. I have to match some face portion on every second. As soon as I will get right face portion then at last I have to call takePicture. So for matching purpose I need image without using takePicture method

Comment: I have already written these codes in my question that they are not working at all for me. Because using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect image quality become too low and I cant accomplish my task using that image. Is there any other alternate method ?